# How can I order desktop icons to fit in the grid?

Tags: unity, 12.10, desktop-icons

I'm often throwing files or directories to the desktop to sort them later. And every time I look at the desktop I am wondering why their icons doesn't fit in rows and columns. Even if I sort by name the items are still not in a row.

Is it possible to have a grid like the filemanager or every other os has?

PS: Using 12.10

Answer (score 1):

When you right-click on the desktop, click on "Keep Aligned" so that it is checked before you organize it by name.  Unless I am wrong, this should realign them to the grid.

It appears that there is a grid, it's just small.  Try dragging icons around and you'll see that they snap to the small grid instead of just staying where you leave them.

Comment: okay, but who needs a grid which is even smaller than the icons ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your desktop
2. Choose keep aligned
3. Right click on your desktop again
4. Organize Desktop by Name

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `iconic` to solve this problem by letting you define a grid size larger than the icons. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.